# How to create an id array in quick.db Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a local black list of members. But I ran into a problem that the bot does not create an array, but inserts only one value

```
const db = require("quick.db")
module.exports.run = async (discord, bot, message, args, p) => {
    db.push(`black_${message.guild.id}`, args[0])
    const bl = db.get(`black_${message.guild.id}`)
    message.channel.send(`${bl}`)
}
module.exports.help = {
    name: 'black',
    aliases: [''],
    description: ''
}
```

Is there any other way to create an array for each server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using await and different constructor might fix your issue.

```js
const { QuickDB } = require("quick.db");
const db = QuickDB();

module.exports.run = async (discord, bot, message, args, p) => {
    await db.push(`black_${message.guild.id}`, args[0])
    const bl = await db.get(`black_${message.guild.id}`)
    message.channel.send(`${bl}`)
}
module.exports.help = {
    name: 'black',
    aliases: [''],
    description: ''
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The solution was wrong, but now the bot cannot create an array when I want to insert an id there, the error is always "Target is not an array."

Comment: Try to initialize the value first maybe, or define another set of value for the db.